# Is there a way to change the background colour of row of list with children?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to highlight selected row.

```
func getListOfDirectories(atPath: URL) -> [URL] {
    var tmp: [URL] = [URL]()
        
    do {
        let dir = try self.fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: atPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        for f in dir {
            if f.isDirectory {
                tmp.append(f)
            }
        }
        return tmp
    } catch {
        return tmp
    }
}

struct FBLSDirectoryData: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let path: URL
    var subDirectories: [FBLSDirectoryData]?
}

struct FBLocationSelector: View {
    @State var title: String = "Copy to"
    @State private var tree: [FBLSDirectoryData] = buildFileTree(atPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0])
    @State private var selectedFolder: FBLSDirectoryData?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(tree, children: \.subDirectories) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedFolder = item
                        print(item.name)
                    }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle(title)
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Many posts say use `listRowBackground` to change background of a row but seems like it only works with `ForEach`. But as you can see, I can't use `ForEach` because of children in `List`.

In this case, how can I change a background colour of a row?

Comment: You want to change background colour of the row on tap gesture?

Comment: @SaketKumar Yup, that's what I want to do. Change the background colour of the row that tapped.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, will shortly come up with response.

Comment: Check the answer, posted does it help if not, let me know I will make change accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there could be many ways to do this.

Given, you want to use List, and you need to change the colour of the row's. How about this simple approach?

```
struct FBLocationSelector: View {
    @State var title: String = "Copy to"
    @State var wasTapped: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("was tapped")
                        wasTapped = !wasTapped
                    }
             .listRowBackground(wasTapped ? Color.purple: Color.gray)

            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle(title)
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Here as an example I am just toggling between two color, you can extend this example as per your requirement.

Comment: This is a demo to convey the concept, this logic to change the state of binded property should be done in ViewModel

Comment: Using `background` in `Text` changes only the background colour of `Text`. I want to change the whole background colour of the selected row.

Comment: I see, let me make some modification

Comment: Does `listRowBackground` works for you without `ForEach` in `List`? As in my question, `listRowBackground` seems like requires `ForEach` somehow. And since I need to use children in `List`, I can't use `ForEach`.

Comment: It does work, I tested it, you can simply run above code to see it

Comment: Did it work for you? If not please let me know, I will enquire further, it does work for me.

Comment: It didn't for me. Maybe because I'm using Ventura and Xcode beta with iOS 16 SDKs.

Comment: strange, you can create a sample git repo with issue, I ll look at that (in iOS 16)

Comment: I just edited my question with more source codes.